# and or operator in validates_presence_of of a Ruby on Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have an entry.rb model and I'm trying to make a semi-complicated validation. I want it to require one or more of the following fields: phone, phone2, mobile, fax, email or website. How would you write the intended code? Would something like this work?

```
validates_presence_of :phone and or :phone2 and or :mobile and or :fax and or :email and or :website
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the "and", "or" by itself will accomplish what you want.

It might be easiest to just write your own custom validation for this.

```
validate :contact_info

def contact_info
  unless phone or phone2 or mobile or fax or email or website
    errors.add_to_base "Must have at least one form of contact info"
  end
end
```

More details here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html